# 'Scenic box'... is it correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions, slang, sentence

I would like to use an expression that refers to a theatre space, a stage space, or any space for performing theatre: the space for a 'scene' in general.

The expression is 'scenic box'. Is it possible to use it for this usage?

I know that 'stage box' is used to describe this (I have found a lot of results in google for 'stage box', but any results for 'scenic box'.)

But I am wondering if this could also be used. I know that 'scenic' also has other meanings like 'pinturesque'.

Could this expression 'scenic box' be understood as a 'pinturesque box', a space for theatre?

Would an English native understand anything by this phrase?

Answer (score 3):

I would say no. The concept of the stage as a box has been well known since Molière, I think, but the word *scenic* in English has an overwhelming connotation of *picturesque*, unfortunately. In other words, while it is possible to refer to the actual stage by the word *scenic*, the sense of *natural scenery* is dominant in the word, which may therefore confuse people.

If you are looking for a different word than (semi-metaphoric) *stage box* or *box set*, then perhaps it would help if you explained exactly why you don't want to use those words. And why don't you use ***the stage***? That is a very common semi-metaphor for the theatre space in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no.  You will run into two problems, the first of which is a collision of meanings.  First, as you noted, with "scenic" meaning picturesque.  Second with the following theatrical terms of art:

- Black**box** theater, an orthotope (3-D analog of a rectangle) performance space that takes its name from the usual color of the interior walls of the building.  The audience sits on three or four sides of a raised stage in the middle of the floor.  As opposed to the usual auditorium arrangement with a proscenium stage at the front.
- **Box** seating, gallery seating at the front and sides of a proscenium stage.
- Stage **box**, a container that serves as the junction for cables for a theater's sound system.

In addition, there is an already-established field of study of the areas of a theatrical performance, and these are named by the word "space."  One way to carve up the total theatrical space is into verbal space and non-verbal acoustic space.  Both of these may have on-stage components and off-stage components, which in turn may be visible or not visible to the audience or the actors or both.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am clear now with this...